# Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM FastCGI, .user.ini not recursive when using Alias

Tags: php, apache

Since Alias(es) are outside for document root. I cannot seem to find a way to make .user.ini recursive. Anyone else have the same experience?

Removing Alias and moving the project with-in document root works as expected. Unfortunately, the project cannot reside in document root.

Comment: *"the project cannot reside in document root"* Why not?

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior (as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)):

> In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned.

Either change the main php.ini file or put a .user.ini in all needed directories.

Comment: Thank you, I did read that but was hoping someone found a workaround.